# Router access with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lan

I am trying to access my router via Selenium so that I can paste a list of websites to block. However, when I try to access the IP (192.168.0.1) I get an invalid argument message.

```
from selenium import webdriver

site = webdriver.Chrome()
site.get('192.168.0.1')
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try adding http:/ in front of it so it is a url.

Comment: why don't you simulate browser request via curl instead of using browser? - just copy request "as cURL" (from development tools of a browser) and paste into your script

Comment: I figured it out. Its using http instead of https.